# Rails security issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I have a rails 4 app on heroku, users can choose an option from a drop down menu ( course name) then click post, and the post will appear on the index page. Someone was able to create a post with an option that was not in the drop down menu at all, how is this possible? What can I do about it?

Comment: Please mention your rails version.

Comment: please post the **views** that has the aforementioned dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the problem. It's very easy to recreate it using chrome developer. Here's the steps on recreating the error

1. Using chrome developer tool, find and inspect the dropdown
2. Right click on it and choose **Edit as html**
3. Add a new value to the dropdown
4. Select the new value and press create

**Now the solution:**

I will just add a validation that checks weather the value passed in is part of the options in the dropdown
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion

Answer (score 1):

Put your options of drop-down menu to private method and permit only those values under your controller. No need to provide attr_accessible under your model if you are writing over there.

Comment: Shouldn't I use validations ? I think that's the better thing to do

Comment: Excuse for late reply, left for holiday. Finks has already answered your query..enjoy :) and thanks to @Finks